# Getting error - 'build.xml does not exist' when building docker file which contains docker commands to run ant targets

Tags: docker, ant

I am creating a docker file to run an ant target which is written in build.xml

My docker file contains below lines.

```
FROM frekele/ant:1.10.1-jdk8

RUN ant -f ./build.xml all
```

Then, I am building docker file from command prompt as below,

```
D:\Support\containarization\cont-new-withfuncactinput\workspace\bas\source\bas\framework\cn\connect_framework> docker build -f ./Dockerfile ./connect-build -t test/connect-build
```

My build.xml and docker file both are located in same above location.

File Structure,

```
D:\Support\containarization\cont-new-withfuncactinput\workspace\bas\source\bas\framework\cn\connect_framework

 - Dockerfile
 - build.xml
```

But, I am getting below error when building docker

```
Buildfile: ./build.xml does not exist!
```

How can I solve this.

Comment: Can you add structure of your files to you post?

Answer (score 1):

You need to push the file to your image before running `ant` else it does not exist there. You have to use [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) for this

Try to modify your Docker file like the following and it should fix your current problem:

```
FROM frekele/ant:1.10.1-jdk8
COPY build.xml ./build.xml
RUN ant -f ./build.xml all
```